# How to find average of the column

Tags: postgresql

Thanks in advance.
How to find avg when the column datatype is character varying in PostgreSQL.

here growth and literacy are character-varying.

```sql
Select avg(cast(GROWTH as float)) from census2;
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMKhL.png]

I have created a table name called `census2`

```sql
create table census2
(
    District      VARCHAR(200)
  , STATE          VARCHAR(250)
  , Growth         NUMERIC
  , Sex_Ratio       NUMERIC
  , Literacy        NUMERIC
);
```

After successful creation while adding CSV file it is displaying errors as
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "Growth"
CONTEXT: COPY census2, line 503, column growth: "Growth"

Comment: What is wrong with your current query?

Comment: Why do you store numbers as text? That's a pretty serious bug in your datamodel. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: Your query seems good. Otherwise you can write it like that `Select avg(GROWTH::numeric) from census2;`

Comment: **Never**, ever store numbers in `varchar` columns. You should fix that before proceeding

Comment: The data contains negative numbers too...

Comment: "0.14"
"0"
"-0.12"
"0.48"
"0.05"
"0.09" the column values are like this

Comment: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "Growth"
SQL state: 22P02   @Philippe

Comment: This is because of decimal separator. Like @a_horse_with_no_name told you, you should never use a varchar for numeric values. You have to replace '.' by your decimal separator like this `select avg(replace(growth,'.',',')::numeric) from census2`

Comment: @RevanthReddyG: Negative numbers are just numbers, and most likely you need a decimal for this column. Fix this problem asap, it's the root cause of your current problem but also of all future problems you will encounter. Check the manual

Comment: I have updated with picture, please check in the question panel pls

Comment: @Philippe when does `numeric` not accept the dot as the decimal separator?

Comment: @Bergi while you've got this error ` invalid input syntax for type numeric`, it means that postgresql can't convert from varchar to numeric (e.g. wrong decimal separator).

Comment: @Revanth Reddy G : What is the decimal separator in your csv file ?

Comment: default one only...decimal it is . and delimiter it is ,

Comment: Thank you #Philippe , #Frank Heikens , #Tim Biegeleisen, #a_horse_with_no_name   for the help. I have solved the issue.